# import Excel into SQL Server using SSIS

Tags: excel, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012, sql-server-data-tools

I want to import the excel sheet data present in my local machines into SQL Server 2012 (installed in the server).
I have seen some examples using SSIS but the excel & Server installed in the same machine.
how to do import from different machines?

Please help

Answer (score 0):

There is no requirement to have the data you wish to load on the same logical machine as the SQL Server installation. You just need SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) installed on a machine which has file access to the Excel file you wish to import and which can connect to the target SQL Server instance.

You might want to re-write your question to ask a specific question or describe the actual problem you're having (or at least tell us what you've already tried) if you want more helpful answers.